# Pass Multiple Arguments to Callback for a StringVar in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working with a small grid of Entry widgets.  It could be 5 x 1 or 5 x 5 or other sizes in between or near those sizes.  When data is entered into an Entry widget, I'd like to be able to pass this on, eventually, to a 2D array of str() variables.

The problem is if I have a number of StringVar() variables, when I use StringVar.trace(), is there a way to pass extra arguments to the callback function?

I currently have:

```
import Tkinter
guiRoot = Tkinter.Tk()
hWindow = Tkinter.Frame(guiRoot)
hWindow.grid();

def callback(*args):
    print "Current value:",sv.get()

sv = Tkinter.StringVar()
sv.trace("w", callback)
Tkinter.Entry(hWindow, textvariable=sv).grid(row=1,column=1)
guiRoot.mainloop()
```

But I'd like to pass on to the callback an X and Y coordinate as well.  Is that possible?

And if I can do it with a callback for a StringVar, can I do it for an Entry widget?

And if I do it with an Entry widget, is there a way I can pass the event to the callback (along with the X and Y info, too) through to the callback function?

In other words, is there some way I can have:

```
def callback(*args):
    print "Array coordinates of Entry (or Stringvar):",x,y
    print "Current value:",sv.get
```

(Yes, I know I'd have to have some way to reference x and y in that callback - so I'd need to know how to do that, too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add whatever arguments you want.

```
def callback(x,y,*args):
    print "x:", x, "y:", y
    print "args:", args
...
sv.trace("w", lambda name1, name2, op, x=100, y=200: callback(x,y,name1,name2,op))
```

Comment: It does not work this way - you change the callback to thi s lambd,a but the labmbda will still be called with no parameters.

Comment: @jsbueno: Does that have an effect on what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I think you just changed my understanding of how this works.  So what I'm doing here is adding a lambda and the **lambda** and not the callback is called.  Then the lambda calls the callback.  Is that correct?

Comment: Another issue on this: I take it this works the same with adding a callback to a widget like Tkinter.Entry?  And can I do that with a bind function, too?  If so, with bind, how can I pass the event on to the callback?

Comment: @Tango: the lambda is called by the trace. The trace will add to the callback the arguments that it already adds. The lambda then will call your callback function. And yes, it works similarly with bindings, though, of course, `bind` only causes a single extra argument to be part of the call, not three like in a trace.

Comment: @jsbueno: I don't understand your comment. In the code I posted, the lambda is called by Tkinter with three extra parameters, and the lambda calls `callback` with five parameters. I don't know what you mean by "called with no parameters".

Comment: If I do this with bind and bind, say, to FocusOut, how do I make sure the event itself is passed to the callback?

Comment: And why is it if I do it as sv.trace("w"), lambda x=100, y=200: callback(x,y) I always get: "TypeError: <lambda>() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"  Are there required variables or is using an assignment as the first argument for lambda an issue?

Comment: @Tango: both trace and bind add parameters when making the callback. Trace adds three, bind adds one.